# dynamodb local: ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation

Tags: log4j2, amazon-dynamodb-local

This is the first time that this issue has occurred to me, I have used DynamoDB local on Linux and Mac and most of the time it worked fine, and now I'm on a different Mac machine, it just throws an error.

The error message that I got was:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. 
Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

I tried installing it via homebrew, but it's throwing the same error. I may have messed up something in my machine or may have missed some configuration.

Below is the screenshot from when I have tried to run it:

[image]

Reference:
Dynamo DB Local: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this AWS Support Forum response by an AWS person](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=962052&#962052) this problem doesn't affect the working of the DynamoDB local instance.

They do intend to fix it so that the messages isn't displayed but it doesn't make a functional difference.

I haven't yet managed to make my local instance work but there may be other, un-associated, issues with that.

[image]

Comment: This should be top answer imo. In my haste, I only read the first two sentences. The last indicates it's using a fallback so there really isn't any usage issues. I really with they would have used the log level of WARNING instead of ERROR in this output.

Answer (score 4):

How I got this to work is to do the following:

Extract the contents of the jar file to a seperate folder

```
jar xf DynamoDBLocal_Orig.jar
```

Add the following to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency
```

Edit the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file and add

```
DynamoDBLocal_lib/log4j-core-2.13.3.jar
```

Compress to a new jar

```
jar cmvf META-INF/MANIFEST.MF DynamoDBLocal.jar *
```

Rename DynamoDBLocal.jar from the base folder to DynamoDBLocal_old.jar

Move the newly created DynamoDBLocal.jar to the base folder.

Download the log4j-core-2.13.3.jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.13.3

Place the log4j-core-2.13.3.jar inside the DynamoDBLocal_lib folder

Run

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

Comment: This is the most tedious solution so far but this one works best. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like zip versions are corrupted. You can download .rar file, it will work. .rar has log4j-core-2.8.jar along with Log4j-api-2.x.jar inside the DynamoDBLocal_lib folder and it is working for me.

Comment: I'd say they got a FUBAR situation at Amazon. I download the `.zip` and `.tar` versions and I'm getting those errors. Even the `amazon/dynamodb-local` docker has that same error.

Comment: Can confirm this is happening using the amazon/dynamodb-local docker on a fresh install done at 7-Nov-2020 08:30 UTC.

Answer (score 3):

I just had exactly the same problem. I tried both the tar and the zip file from Europe (frankfurt) region. The problem persisted. I can see the log4j-core package in the classpath, but somehow it doesn't get picked up. Not sure if the other AWS regions are corrupted too.

I solved it by asking a colleague of mine to share his DynamoDB folder. He downloaded it a few months ago, and it's working like a charm.

Solution: AWS needs to fix the package, otherwise see if you can ask a colleague to help you out.