# Boto3 timeout connecting to local dynamodb but can curl

Tags: docker, boto3, amazon-dynamodb-local

I have been attempting to follow the various instructions and troubleshooting to get a docker container to connect to another docker container running local `dynamodb` via `boto3`. References/troubleshooting so far:

- [In compose, can just use automatic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55602574/putting-to-local-dynamodb-table-with-python-boto3-times-out). Incidentally I tried explicitly specifying a shared network but could not succeed this way.
- [Make sure to use the resource name from compose, not localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55602574/putting-to-local-dynamodb-table-with-python-boto3-times-out)
- [Github repo with a template](https://github.com/CT83/DynamoDB-Python-Docker-Compose-Starter-Kit)

Dockerfile (`docker build -t min-example:latest .`):

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN pip install boto3

RUN mkdir /app
COPY min_example.py /app
WORKDIR /app
```

Docker compose (`min-example.yml`):

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  app:
    image: min-example:latest
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`min_example.py`

```
import boto3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
                         endpoint_url='http://db:8000',
                         region_name='dummy',
                         aws_access_key_id='dummy',
                         aws_secret_access_key='dummy')
    existing_tables = [t.name for t in list(ddb.tables.all())]
    print(existing_tables)
    existing_tables = [t.name for t in list(ddb.tables.all())]
    print(existing_tables)
```

Run with

```
docker-compose run -f min-example.yml app python min_example.py
```

It hangs on the `ddb.tables.all()` call, and times out with the error:

> botocore.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: Read timeout on endpoint URL: "http://db:8000/"

Interestingly, I can curl:

```
docker-compose -f min-example.yml run app curl http://db:8000/
```

> {"__type":"com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#MissingAuthenticationToken","message":"Request must contain either a valid (registered) AWS access key ID or X.509 certificate."}

Which suggests the containers can communicate.

Comment: What happens when you run `docker-compose up` instead of the individual run commands?

Comment: Interesting, looks like dynamo image throwing this error: "ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console..."

Comment: Confirmed amazon/dynamodb image is up to date with the latest.

Comment: The error might not be a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549078/dynamodb-local-error-statuslogger-log4j2-could-not-find-a-logging-implementatio. Indeed, I can now see that **the script completes successfully**. Why is `run` not working?!